# 3D tensor of diagonal matrices

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, algebra

I have a matrix A with m rows and n columns. I want a 3D tensor of dimension m*n*n such that the tensor consists out of m diagonal matrices formed by each of the columns of A. In other words every column of A should be converted into a diagonalized matrix and all those matrices should form a 3D tensor together.

This is quite easy to do with a for loop. But I want to do it without to improve speed.

I came up with a bad and inefficient way which works, but I hope someone can help me with finding a better way, which allows for large A matrices.

```
# I use python
# import numpy as np
n = A.shape[0] # A is an n*k matrix
k = A.shape[1]

holding_matrix = np.repeat(np.identity(k), repeats=n, axis=1) # k rows with n*k columns
identity_stack = np.tile(np.identity(n),k) #k nxn identity matrices stacked together

B = np.array((A@holding_matrix)*identity_stack)
B = np.array(np.hsplit(B,k)) # desired result of k n*n diagonal matrices in a tensor
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I think this question is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, as it deals with *working* code that can be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = A.shape[0] # A.shape == (n, k)
k = A.shape[1]

B = np.zeros_like(A, shape=(k, n*n)) # to preserve dtype and order of A

B[:, ::(n+1)] = A.T
B = B.reshape(k, n, n)
```